# build libevent under windows with cygwin?

Tags: c, windows, libevent

I build libevent-2.0.16-stable under cygwin-windows with multi-thread feature support but it's seem that `configure` didn't detect environment as WIN32, so it did not include `evthread_win32.c` as a part of build process, a try call to `evthread_use_windows_threads` cause symbol not found.
So i try to set WIN32 flag like `CFLAGS=WIN32 ./configure` and it did not work too.  So what's is the properly way?

Comment: Libevent developer here. I've never tried building Libevent on Cygwin for windows: only with mingw and msvc.   So there might be a bug there! It looks like evthread_win32.c is included when BUILD_WIN32 is defined in configure.in, and BUILD_WIN32 is defined by configure.in only when the preprocessor macros "WIN32" is defined by your compiler.  Does cygwin GCC define any preprocessor macros that indicate that it is WIN32?  [ETA: if you find a solution here, please let us know on the libevent mailing list or bugtracker so we can fix it for others too]

Comment: I don't think cygwin define a WIN32 flag, configure script show a line such as "checking for WIN32... no,  checking for CYGWIN... yes"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So i just configured to use non-cygwin compiller `./configure --binpath=[path to directory with the compiler] CC=[path to my mingw gcc.exe]` and then just ran `make`