# Installing gearman on windows 7 through cygwin and get "configure: error: Unable to find libevent"

Tags: cygwin, gearman, libevent

I'm a newbie trying to install gearman on windows through cygwin using the tutorial here:  http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/

I need to install gearman to develop on my windows 7 laptop.

I've installed libevent in my `C:\cygwin\libeventInstall` directory but when I do a `./configure` on gearman it gives me the `error: configure: error: Unable to find libevent`

I've read that I need to install libevent-devel.  I don't know what libevent-devel is and how I go about installing it through cygwin.   I've found a bunch of .rpm install files for libevent-devel but I don't think I can install that on windows.  I've also found a libevent-devel-2.0.11-1.tar.bz2 but it contains a bunch of header files and no configure file.  There doesn't seem to be any documentation on exactly how to install libevent-devel on cygwin.

Been stuck for a few days.  Any pointers would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: for the love of all that is right in the world and your own sanity - have you considered using virtual box, or any kind of VM so you can run linux virtualised on your laptop. Much much pain lies on your current path.

Comment: @JamesButler Thou you are right, often you need to run composer locally and if you need to run composer localy and you are using certain gearman packages, those often require gearman to be installed.
Thus, at times, we need to solve that problem.
:-(

Answer (score 2):

You need to build LibEvent, it is not included in Cygwin. I *haven't tried this*, but a [google search](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.libevent.user/338) led to the following instructions:

1. you need

   - http://win6.jp/Cygwin/cygwin-1.5.25-15-ipv6-0.22.zip
   - http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent-1.4.9-stable.tar.gz
2. unpack cygwin-1.5.25-15-ipv6-0.22.zip into you cygwin folder about this files read site http://win6.jp/Cygwin/
3. in libevent http.c file add line ---> #define EAI_SYSTEM 11
4. now install libevent
5. ./configure
6. make
7. make install

I also found this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321187/build-libevent-under-windows-with-cygwin) interesting since the Libevent devs were commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Gave up on using cygwin.  Tried a reinstalling libevent as per the above and re-running gearman ./configure and the "configure: error: Unable to find libevent" persists.

Took James Butler's advice and am using virtualbox instead.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you access your gearman job server, client and workers in Windows if you use VirtualBox ?
Just give me a brief insight. I want to run my code in Windows only !
I am also having a hard time installing Gearman on Windows.